My Validation accuracy is stuck between 10% and 11%
This is my code for training loop
def train_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer) -> None:
    # size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    running_loss = 0, 0
    # set the model to training mode - imp for batch norm and dropout layers
    model.train()
    for batch, (image_batch, labels) in tqdm(
        enumerate(dataloader), unit="batch", total=len(dataloader)
    ):
        (image_batch, labels) = (
            image_batch.to(config.DEVICE),
            labels.to(config.DEVICE),
        )
        # compute the prediction
        prediction = model(image_batch)
        loss = loss_fn(prediction, labels)

        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        running_loss += loss.item()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            # loss, current = loss.item(), batch * config.BATCH_SIZE + len(image_batch)
            print(
                f"Batch{batch+1:5d} loss:{running_loss/100:.3f}"
            )  # since i am adding loss for every 100 bath, so i need to display average loss for each batch
            # print(f"Training Loss: {loss:>7f} | [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}] ")
            running_loss = 0.0


This is my code for validation loop
    model.eval()
    num_batches = len(dataloader)
    validation_loss = 0
    validation_correct = 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for image_batch, labels in dataloader:
            image_batch, labels = (
                image_batch.to(config.DEVICE),
                labels.to(config.DEVICE),
            )
            pred = model(image_batch)
            validation_loss += loss_fn(pred, labels).item()
            validation_correct += (
                (pred.argmax(1) == labels).type(torch.float).sum().item()
            )

    validation_loss /= num_batches
    validation_accuracy = 100 * validation_correct / len(dataloader.dataset)

    # Use logging library instead of print (optional)
    print(
        f"Validation Error: \n Accuracy: {validation_accuracy:.1f}%, Avg loss: {validation_loss:.8f}"
    )


My model, loss function and optimizers (lr = 1e-3)
    model = Network().to(config.DEVICE)
    loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=config.LEARNING_RATE)

This is training and validation loop
    for epoch in range(config.NUM_EPOCHS):
        print(f"EPOCH: {epoch+1}\n -----------------------------------")
        train_loop(train_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer)
        test_loop(valid_dataloader, model, loss_fn)


and finally this is the configuration
BATCH_SIZE = 16
LEARNING_RATE = 1e-3
NUM_EPOCHS = 20
CHANNEL_MEAN = (0.485, 0.456, 0.406)
CHANNEL_STD = (0.229, 0.224, 0.225)
INPUT_SIZE = 224
MOMENTUM = 0.9

I am trying to increase the validation accuracy but the accuracy seems to be jumping back and forth between 10 and 11% while average loss of the validation set seems low i.e. 2.3 yet accuracy is 11%. I am not understanding what is exactly happening with the code.
The screenshot of 12th epoch is :
enter image description here
